# Why when I want to open a folder from Visual Studio Code does the screen go crazy?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-22.04

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knId1.jpg)

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS in VirtualBox,  I have assigned **10GB** of RAM, **8** Processors and **256MB** with **3D** video memory to the virtual machine.

I have tried changing the hardware config in virtualbox settings and updating the virtual machine along with installing the vbox guest additions, but it is still the same :/

Answer (score 0):

If you installed it via snap, try the deb version in case the versions are different: https://code.visualstudio.com/download